# jenkins console showing errors while doing java -jar jenkins.war

Tags: jenkins

> [33mJan 09, 2018 4:31:06 PM hudson.model.UpdateCenter updateDefaultSite
>       WARNING: Upgrading Jenkins. Failed to update the default Update Site 'default'.
>       Plugin upgrades may fail.
>       net.sf.json.JSONException : Missing value. at character 29 of 
>       background-color:#425563;
>       }

I am getting the above error in Jenkins console of command prompt due to this am not able to install any plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try following [these](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/) steps. Error might be solved